# Different uses of $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference/advantages of using the $(docu...) with your variables and functions defined inside, from using it with a function and then calling it inside the $(docu...)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    initialize();
});
function initialize(){
    hello
}
```

over using this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        hello
});
```

Comment: This is not a real question, is it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `$(document).ready` and you should learn basics of JavaScript or even programming concepts.

Comment: You didn't understand the question. Hello is just an example.

Comment: `$(initialize)` works. Also there is a ton of information on any search engine you want to use for this subject. I reccommend searching for this information since you will learn a lot that you obviously don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These four options all create exactly the same result with declining flexibility:

### Example #1

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    initialize();
});

function initialize(){
    hello();
}
```

### Example #2

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){
    hello();
}
```

### Example #3

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        hello();
});
```

### Example #4

```
$(document).ready(hello);
```

In the first example, you are creating an anonymous function that will be called at document.ready time.  That anonymous function calls a separate function `initialize()`.  Because `initialize()` is a separate function, it could also be called by other code.

In the second example, you just avoid the anonymous function and pass a reference to the `initialize` function directly.  This works slightly faster than the first example (one less function call), but is less flexible if you wanted to call more than one function besides `initialize()` from the `document.ready()` handler.

In the third example, you just remove the outer `initialize()` function and just call the one thing inside it that it was doing from an anonymous function.

In the fourth example, the anonymous function is again removed and you just pass a direct reference to the `hello` function so it will be called directly without any intervening functions.

The first option gives you the most flexibility because you can call multiple things inside of `initialize()` and you can also call `initialize()` from other places in your program.  If you don't need those flexibilities, you can pick any one of the other four options as they all produce the same results, each with a little less flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, you can use the `initialize` function again later. If you put the `hello` code directly inside `$(document).ready()`'s function, you can't refer to that code again later.

Comment: Additionally, when you put the hello code directly inside the document.ready function, it will execute this directly instead of being pointed to a separate function.